# Arduino Micro Ports disconnects after a second of connecting to PC

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I was testing my micro with esp8266 (Wifi Module) .

My micro does not show the COM port when its connected . As soon as I put the USB cable in and check the device manager on my Windows 10.
It shows the port for a second and then it disconnects.

Earlier it was working perfectly. Is it something to do with my testing Wifi module?

I tried disconnecting everything , use just the micro ,still the problem persists. Any inputs?

Comment: @CConard96 or still better, [Electronics Stackexchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @CConard96 or still beter Arduino stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

USB allows 100mA current to the connected device and connected device have to negotiate bigger power consumption limit (up to 500mA).

The ESP8266 power consumption is about 170mA in peaks, so over current is detected on USB port and it gets disconnected. Recommended power supply should deliver at least 1A according some [sites](http://www.esp8266.nu/index.php/Power) about ESP.